# Is there a way to filter an Access Database column based off a specific sub-string?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access Database with over 5 million rows and I can't seem to figure out how to filter it properly.

Each cell/row has data similar to the below:

3255128617[11666]21128351869

I am trying to filter the data based on the text within the [ brackets, so that only rows that have [11666] in the string are returned.

I have tried using the Like query with different wildcards but nothing seems to work.

Is there a simple way to filter my column so that only cells that contain [11166] anywhere in the string are returned?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the basic string operations can't do the job use Regex.  for example see here: https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-regex-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Use *Like* in the criteria:

```
WHERE [YourField] Like "*[[11666]]*"
```